# 3D printed houses and energy efficiency in Germany

Tags: 3d-printing

I have just learned that [in Germany you wouldn't be able to *print* a house](https://www.welt.de/finanzen/immobilien/article147422556/Werden-Haeuser-bald-vom-3D-Drucker-gebaut.html) because of existing rules, especially regarding energy efficiency.

Isn't it possible to print an insulating inlayer to fulfil this standard?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is possible to meet the energy efficiency standards - the article itself suggests that 3D printed houses have the *potential* to exceed traditional building methods for efficiency.

The point that the article is making under the "Deutschland tut sich schwer mit dem 3-D-Druck" heading, is that there are just *a lot* of regulatory hurdles. Paperwork. Not only does your potential 3D printed house need to be suitably efficient, but you need to *prove to the authorities* that it will be, before you've built it, or you won't get a permit to start the building.

For such a new technology with little existing data to draw upon, convincing those in charge that your design meets *all* of the standards (energy efficiency is just one example) will be extremely difficult, and explains why research into this area is not a priority for the established house builders in the country.